# Combine (overlay) two factorplots in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, boxplot, swarmplot

I need to add `swarmplot` to `boxplot` in matplotlib, but I don't know how to do it with `factorplot`. I think I can iterate with subplots, but I would like to learn how to do it with seaborn and factorplot.

A simple [example](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.swarmplot.html) (plotting by using the same axis `ax`):

```
import seaborn as sns
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
ax = sns.boxplot(x="tip", y="day", data=tips, whis=np.inf)
ax = sns.swarmplot(x="tip", y="day", data=tips, color=".2")
```

The result: [image]

In my case, I need to overlay the swarm factorplot:

```
g = sns.factorplot(x="sex", y="total_bill",
                      hue="smoker", col="time",
                      data=tips, kind="swarm",
                      size=4, aspect=.7);
```

and **boxplot**

I can't figure out how to use axes (extract from `g`)?

Something like:

```
g = sns.factorplot(x="sex", y="total_bill",
                          hue="smoker", col="time",
                          data=tips, kind="box",
                          size=4, aspect=.7);
```

[image]

I want something like this, but with `factorplot` and `boxplot` instead of `violinplot`

[image]

Comment: You would need 2 boxplots, because you have two swarmplots, right? Wouldn't it make more sense to directly plot two swarmplots and two boxplots which can be easily overlayed?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, absolutely! I want exactly as you suggested, but I'm struggling to do it. Any easy fix?

Comment: The edit is confusing. The plot you show that you want to have only has a single subplot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of trying to overlay the two subplots of a factorplot with individual boxplots (which is possible, but I don't like it), one can just create the two subplots individually.

You would then loop over the groups and axes an plot a pair of box- and swarmplot to each.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2, sharex=True, sharey=True)

for ax, (n,grp) in zip(axes, tips.groupby("time")):
    sns.boxplot(x="sex", y="total_bill", data=grp, whis=np.inf, ax=ax)
    sns.swarmplot(x="sex", y="total_bill", hue="smoker", data=grp, 
                  palette=["crimson","indigo"], ax=ax)
    ax.set_title(n)
axes[-1].get_legend().remove()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Fab! You simply read my mind. This is exactly what I needed and struggled for several hours :( Many thanks!!!